# Content cannot translated and tests are failed on jest in next-i18next

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, next.js, react-testing-library, next-i18next

I am using Next-i18next package for my localization purposes in my project.

I successfully rendered translated content on my UI. But when I try to test my content and text with enzym (shallow testing) and jest-dom, the tests are failed because the translated content does not render correctly.

I have tried various solutions:

- https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing
- [Mocking useTranslation for i18n in JEST not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266605/mocking-usetranslation-for-i18n-in-jest-not-working)
- [How can I enable react-i18n translation file to be used in the unit tests done with react-testing-library and jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57148082/how-can-i-enable-react-i18n-translation-file-to-be-used-in-the-unit-tests-done-w)
- [How do I mock react-i18next and i18n.js in jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45020842/how-do-i-mock-react-i18next-and-i18n-js-in-jest)
- I tried to wrap my test component with  `<I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}> </I18nextProvider>`

No one is working for me.

My test file: form.test.tsx

```
describe("form", () => {
 it('should render the basic fields', () => {
    render(<MyFormComponent/>)
}
expect(
      screen.getByRole('textbox', { name: /First name/i })
    ).toBeInTheDocument();
})

 it('should match snapshot', () => {
    store = mockStore(initialState);
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyFormComponent/>)
}
```

I get this type of error from my failed tests:

> TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find a label with the text of: First Name

Because instead of 'First Name' string, the snapshot renders the 'firstName' key in translation json.

Any suggestion and solution will be welcome.

Comment: Can you please share the code for the component under test?